# Dart test fails even though it throws expected exception

Tags: dart, testing

I have created the following dart test...

```
import 'package:is_a_test/is_a_test.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class MyException implements Exception {

}

void throws() {
  throw MyException();
}

void main() {
  test('calculate', () {
    expect(() => throws(), throwsA(isA<MyException>));
  });
}
```

The expected result would be a test pass. But instead it fails with...

```
Expected: throws <Closure: () => TypeMatcher<MyException> from Function 'isA': static.>
  Actual: <Closure: () => void>
   Which: threw <Instance of 'MyException'>
stack test/is_a_test_test.dart 9:3    throws
test/is_a_test_test.dart:9
main.<fn>.<fn>
```

Answer (score 3):

`isA<MyException>` is a *function* that returns a `Matcher`.  The failure indicated this, although it might be hard to understand:

> ```
> Expected: throws <Closure: () => TypeMatcher<MyException> from Function 'isA': static.>
> ```

This means that you were expecting something that throws a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), essentially a function.

You instead need to invoke that function by using `isA<MyException>()`.